# unwanted distances

Tags: css

Why is the distance between the top of the page and the text "Profuture" in the header class 29 pixels instead of 20 pixels?

Why is the distance between the top of the page and the text "Probable Future" in the sub_header class 21 pixels instead of 20 pixels?

Why is the distance between the bottom of the page and the text "Copyright © 2008 Profuture.com" in the footer class 24 pixels instead of 20 pixels?

test.css:

```
body
{
    background-color: #CACACA;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a
{
    color: #424242;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover
{
    color: #424242;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a.menu_link
{
    color: #424242;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a.menu_link:hover
{
    color: #424242;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header a
{
    color: #A40008;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#sub_header a
{
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#container
{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 750px;
}

#header
{
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#sub_header
{
    margin: 0 0 20px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
#footer
{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#main
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#main_top
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 20px;
}
#main_bottom
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 20px;
}

.content
{
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 510px;
}
.content_top
{
    color: #A40008;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.content_bottom
{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menu
{
    border-left: #8C8484 1px solid;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    width: 139px;
}
.menu_top
{
    color: #A40008;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.menu li
{
    list-style-type: circle;
}
label
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#clear
{
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
        ProFuture
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" /></head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="link1">ProFuture</a>
    </div>
    <div id="sub_header">
        <a href="link1">Probable Future</a>
    </div>
    <div id="main_top">
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content_top">
                Page
            </div>
            <div class="content_bottom">
                <a href="http://www.test.com/">http://www.test.com/</a>
            </div>
            <div class="content_top">
                Interpretation
            </div>
            <div class="content_bottom">
                testtesttest
                testtesttest
                testtesttest
            </div>
            <div class="content_top">
                Author
            </div>
            <div class="content_bottom">
                tes...@test.com
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menu_top">Account</div>
            <br>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="create">Create</a></li><li><a href="read">Read</a></li><li><a href="login">Log In</a></li><li><a href="logout">Log Out</a></li><li><a href="update">Update</a></li><li><a href="delete">Delete</a></li>            </ul>
            <br>
            <div class="menu_top">Statistic</div>
            <br>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="create">Create</a></li><li><a href="read">Read</a></li>            </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="clear"></div>
        </div>
    <div id="main_bottom">
    </div>
    <div id="footer"><strong>Copyright &copy; 2008</strong> <a href="#">Profuture.com</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should adjust the `line-height` on the text elements in question.

Inline elements, such as text and the `<a>` in your example, are actually in "boxes". The distance between the edge of these inline boxes and the text is determined by the font-size, which is *not* the size of an actual glyph per se. Different browsers render default line-height differently (and this can differ per font). Usually it's 1.2x the font-size, which means that you would be able to set `line-height: 1;` and thereby solve the problem. In your case, it looks like `line-height: 0.7;` on the text in the header solves the problem there. However, you'll have to calculate this wherever you need to be that exact.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be the large font-size of `#header`. You might try adjusting line-height to compensate for that.

Comment: It looks like this worked given a quick test in Chrome.  I was having the same issue, and didn't know about the line-height attribute.

Comment: I also think this answer would work - give `line-height:20px` to each of your header anchors and then `line-height:12px` to the footer.

If that doesn't do it then add `height:20px` and `height:12px` to the headers and footer respectively.

Comment: With 20 of line-height to headers and 12 of line-height to footer, the first distance becomes 21, the second distance becomes 17 on Firefox and 20 on Chrome and the third distance becomes 21.

Comment: With 20 of height to headers and 12 of height to footer, the first distance becomes 29, the second distance becomes 14 on Firefox and 17 on Chrome and the third distance becomes 24.

Comment: With 20 of line-height and 20 of height to headers, 12 of line-height and 12 of height to footer, the first distance becomes 21, the second distance becomes 17 on Firefox and 20 on Chrome and the third distance becomes 21.

Comment: You're not going to get fonts to be pixel-perfect.  Available fonts and versions will vary from machine to machine and the characters themselves won't always occupy the full space.

Answer (score 1):

The [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/60) and/or [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843) are priceless tools to sort out that kind of problem. In Web Developer, use "CSS" > "Show style information". In Firebug, right click the element and click "inspect element".

Comment: Great point. And note that Chrome and Safari have similar functionality built into the browsers now.